# insert into an array from an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays

i am doing a hotel room booking system.

i created two array list which is days and rooms.

i created buttons to add value into array list.
example: if monday clicked, then ("monday") inserted into days's array list.
if monday and tuesday clicked, then ("monday") and ("tuesday) inserted into days's array list.

now after all the information is done  how do i insert the array list which is days and rooms
into a array, which this array is to function is to store these information as a booking, then use this array to compare with another booking array weather the room being booked or not

Comment: somebody can help me or teach what am i wrong?
rather just give me a negative vote....T.T

Comment: would you please clarify how you want to compare between two arrays? 

Then, maybe I could try to suggest another idea for storing room/day information than your one which i'm not very clear about.

Comment: @Quintus.Zhou   my idea is comparing two array if ==1 then not available.....

Comment: still not very clear, what does `if==1` mean?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the question you are trying to insert two different ArrayLists into one Array ??

If you are trying to do so.. that is not a good way to do it.. instead create a class having variables as **day** and **room** get values in object of that class.. than store it in a array..

hope this helps..

Comment: but it will be many days get selected how i say it into array?

Comment: You can use some other data structure also like "Map" instead of Arraylist which looks more appropriate according to your problem..

Comment: map....i is done some research, it gave me some idea...
maybe my days can use map..then room that chosen can input into day's map...this idea ok?

Comment: May would be a good choice, put the room as the KEY, put a List  which contains all reservation date as VALUE.

<br>Reservations:
{ 
 room-1 = [Monday, Tuesday], room-2 = [Sunday], room-3 = []
}

In case you want to check whether a room is booked or not, just retrieve the corresponding List by Map.get(room), if the List is empty then the room is not reserved at all.

Answer (score 0):

jvaa.util.Map would be a good choice, put the room as the KEY, put a List  which contains all reservation date as VALUE.

`Reservations:
{ 
 room-1 = [Monday, Tuesday], room-2 = [Sunday], room-3 = []
}`

In case you want to check whether a room is booked or not, just retrieve the corresponding List and check size of the List, if the List is empty then the room is not reserved at all.

Exampe for checking reservation of room_1

`Map.get(room_1).isEmputy()`

For you second comment

Q1: Map.get(room_1).add(DAY-1), for reservation ROOM-1 in DAY-1

Q2:Depends on how do you want to model it. In case you have 3 floors, it is able to index FLOOR/ROOMS in another KEY-VALUE data type , so that you can firstly find all rooms in specific floor by the floor key, then try to add a new room in that floor.

{ FLOOR-1 : [ROOM-1, ROOM-2, ROOM-3, ...], FLOOR-2 : [ROOM-4, ROOM-5, ...]}

Comment: what the code for inside value to reservation?  i have 3 floor with 10room ...so i need add all room in map?

Comment: see the revised answer